# Compare an array of dictionaries with it self for similarities

Tags: arrays, json, swift, core-data, struct

I use core data to store a JSON file. The core data is an array of dictionaries, [TestMO], and one of these dictionaries is an array of keywords (not a standard .count - maybe 3, 5, 7 etc). So what I am trying to do is to to compare the entire database with it self to find the objects, TestMO's, which have a similar (or > 50%) matching keywords. I tried a loop inside a loop but is just too time consuming and a terrible user experience. Any ideas how I can achieve this efficiently? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Use your knowledge to reduce the complexity

If your array has *n* elements and you want to compare each element with every other element, you end up with *n*(n-1)/2* comparisons. For *n=10* you get 45 comparisons, for *n=100* you get 4950, for *n=1000* half a million, for *n=1000000* half a trillion. Your complexity grows quadratically, with *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

You will need to use your statistical knowledge on your array and how your analysis is used to beat this complexity. For instance, if your *n* is relatively small and you need to run your analysis only once, don't bother optimizing and just let it run for a night.

If you want to run your analysis every time a user adds another element, you may want to compare just this new element to all the other *n* elements, at a complexity of only *O(n)*.

To further optimize, you may want to establish an index, say a dictionary that associates a set of elements to each keyword. Establishing the index will still be time-consuming and memory-intensive, on the order of *O(n*m)* if every keyword occurs on average *m* times on the existing elements. Depending on what you want to analyse, comparing a new element with *k* keywords, you might be able to get a complexity of the order of *O(m*k)* for adding that new element. If *m* and *k* are much smaller than *n*, that might reduce your waiting time significantly.

This question has nothing to do with `swift` nor `core-data`, but with [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) and `time-complexity` in particular. Please add the latter tag to your question.